# Accessing user stories of another project

Tags: azure-devops

I got two projects for similar type of work that are kept separate for few key reasons.
One of the projects is a master project, while the other is a subset or child equivalent.

Is there any way the master project (and the relevant team) can get access to all the user stories of the subset project?

I know within the project i can just assign multiple area paths but this is now crossing projects, not sure if its possible or if there is a extension that does this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can link work items between projects. In this case, you should link work items in the Links tab (or Related work section).

[image]

Then you can find linked work item in the backlogs (with "i" character):

[image]

Additionally, you can use work item queries with the "Query across project" property:

[image]

Comment: That creates a link but doesn't add it to master board to interact with. E.g. Adding area path to master board would work but doesn't allow if it's in another project

Comment: @Aeseir, yes, this is a limitation of boards in multiple projects. Areas do not help here because the same area paths have different ids in different projects. Check Delivery Plans also as Leo Liu mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> I know within the project i can just assign multiple area paths but this is now crossing projects, not sure if its possible or if there is a extension that does this.

You could try to use the [Delivery Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops&tabs=plans-preview), which you can view multiple backlogs and multiple teams across your whole account. You can interact with the plan with simple drag-and-drop operations to update or modify the schedule, opening cards, expanding and collapsing teams, and more.

To get this feature, see [Manage or enable features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops) and turn on New Delivery Plans：

[image]

This new version of Delivery Plans provides support for the following tasks:

- Epics can be added to a delivery plan
- Work item cards can span iteration boundaries
- Drag and drop borders show when a work item starts and ends
- You can add backlog items to a team from a plan
- Stakeholders can view plans